# Drag multiple items with ng2Dragula

Tags: css, angular, drag-and-drop, ng2-dragula

I am using the library ng2-Dragula and I'm trying to move multiple items while dragging. I have an array of items and with ShiftKey and CtrlKey the property `marked` is set to `true/false`. On the moment to drag the code I do is:

```
this.subs.add(this.dragulaService.drag("peoples")
.subscribe(({ name, el, source }) => {
  console.log(name);
  console.log(el);
  console.log(source);
  for(let x = 0; x<source.children.length; x++){
    source.children[x].className = 'active';
    source.children[x].className = 'gu-mirror'
    source.children[x].className = 'gu-transit'
  } 
})
);
```

With the loop, I am able to set the style to the items, but not to add them to move, and its only move the member `el`. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Does Dragula gives the drag and drop multiple items ?

Comment: No, it's not possible, so we have to implement by ourselves

Comment: There is a workaround currently from one of [github issue](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/50#issuecomment-384799256): [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jw5e4c3c/9/)